# What is the best method to treat multiple objects, without retreating already treated objects?

Tags: java, arraylist, equals, hashset, hashcode

Say I'd like to treat multiple objects of some class `Object` over the course of some higher level algorithm, with some method `treat(Object o)`. In this algorithm, identical objects may occur (not having the same address), and so I don't want to treat every one of these identical objects, only the first one appearing, ignoring others.

A simple solution would be to implement an `ArrayList` structure to stock all already treated objects, named `treated`, and do as follows.

```
if (!treated.contains(o)){
    treat(o);
    treated.add(o);
}
```

However, I think the `contains` method runs in linear time, whereas using a `HashSet` instead of an `ArrayList` would be able to do it in constant time.

Here is my problem though : **same hashcodes do not ensure equality**. In other words, using `HashSet treated` as follows :

```
if (!treated.contains(o)){
    treat(o);
    treated.add(o);
}
```

might not treat all distinct objects, since some object `o1` might end up having the same hashcode as a different object `o2`. If `o1` is treated, then `o2` will not be, and vice versa.
Would a `HashMap treated`, used alongside some `equals()`, be better suited for my problem?

```
if (treated.containsKey(o.hashCode())){
    Object o2 = treated.get(o.hashCode());
    if (!o.equals(o2)){
        treat(o);
    }
} else {
    treat(o);
    treated.put(o.hashCode(), o);
}
```

What would be the recommended method to this problem?

NB : I've seen comments about using a "perfect hashcode", *i.e.* a hashcode assigning a unique value to every unique object, thus not obtaining similar hashcodes for different objects. I don't see this as a solution, since (theoretically speaking) I can have any amount of distinct objects to treat, whereas hashcodes are of type `int` which effectively limits the amount of distinct hashcodes.

Comment: *"Would a HashMap treated, used alongside some equals(), be better suited for my problem?"* -> You're expected to override both `.equals` and `.hashCode` anyway. And *"a hashcode assigning a unique value to every unique object"* seems to be at odds with the point of hash codes.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that a `HashSet` *only* looks at hash codes. It doesn't. From the docs for `HashSet.contains`: "More formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e such that Objects.equals(o, e)."

Comment: @JonSkeet From the fact that there's no get method in `HashSet`s, I assumed `HashSet`s do not store the objects, only their hashcodes, implying the `contains` method only compared hashcodes. Apparently I assumed wrong ! So if I'm not mistaken, this solves my problem, I can simply use a `HashSet`. You can post that answer if you'd like.

Comment: @J.Schmidt: There's no `get` method because there's no kind of key or index to get a single value *by* - but it's still a set... you can iterate over it etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet If it's possible to do an `equals` method on the object, than it should be possible to have a `get` function as well : instead of comparing the object with `equals`, just return the object. Maybe the point you're trying to make however, is that such a `get` would not run in constant time?

Comment: @J.Schmidt: It would be *possible*, but it doesn't exist (which I've found to be annoying sometimes, as I've wanted to keep a set of "canonical" values) and isn't really part of the normal "set" operations. It's not inherent to a set in the way that "get by index" or "get by key" are for List and Map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In other words, using `HashSet treated` as follows [...]
>   might not treat all distinct objects, since some object o1 might end up having the same 
>   hashcode as a different object o2

This is based on a mistaken assumption that `HashSet.contains` only checks the hash code. It doesn't - it uses the hash code to find equal *candidates*, but then checks for actual equality with `equals` as normal.

From the [`contains` method documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains(java.lang.Object)):

> Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e such that `Objects.equals(o, e)`.

Comment: As a side note, the contract of `Set` makes operations like `if(!set.contains(o)) { … set.add(o); }` obsolete. You can simply use `if(treated.add(o)) treat(o);`.